# How to make an XMLHttpRequest that inserts JSON data into HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, json, request, xmlhttprequest

Hey I'm trying to make and **XMLHttpRequest** that gets a **JSON** , and afterwards **inserts** an specific field of it into HTML.

For example insert just the data of Angelo his `name` , `lastname` and `age`, each field in a different HTML element

The problem is that I can't get the correct data in the HTML elements , it keeps appearing undefined inside the HTML element `name`

**I'm not allowed by my boss to use jQuery**

**HTML**

```
<h2>Nombre</h2>
<h3 class="name" id="name">Alex</h3>
<br>
<h2>Segundo Nombre</h2>
<h3 class="lastname">Synshit</h3>
<br>
<h2>Edad</h2>
<h3 class="age">199</h3>
```

**JS**

```
function loadProfile(){

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "../json/perfil.json";

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var myArr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=myArr[0];
      }
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();


}
```

**JSON**

```
{
    "angelo":{
            "Name":"Angelo",
            "LastName":"Giuseppe",
            "Age":19
        },

      "hugo":{
            "Name":"Hugo",
            "LastName":"Dóminguez",
            "Age":25
        },

      "edgar":{
            "Name":"Edgar",
            "LastName":"Villareal",
            "Age":35
            },

        "salvador":{
            "Name":"Salvador",
            "LastName":"Ramirez",
            "Age":20
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line `document.getElementById("name").innerHTML=myArr[0];` you're indexing into an array, but your JSON file contains an object. You'd have to either change it to `myArr.angelo` or change your JSON file to contain an array.

Comment: let me try with that

Comment: using myArr.angelo returns in the HTML the next: "[object Object]" but not the name mmmm

Comment: becuase you are accesing object, you have to go one level deeper. myArr.angelo.Name. Design your json in form of collections

Comment: thats right , it worked !, do you know how can I make a part of "myArr.angelo.Name" dynamic?, for example angelo being a variable

Comment: angelo is already a variable, you can edit the value and it'll change your local copy, but I highly recommend formatting your JSON the way @Riz showed. And I'm happy to help, if you think I solved your problem you can mark my answer as a solution

Answer (score 0):

The way you have formatted your json is incorrect.
Design your json like this and you should be able to access the way you are accessing now.

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Angelo",
    "LastName": "Giuseppe",
    "Age": 19
  },
  {
    "Name": "Hugo",
    "LastName": "Dóminguez",
    "Age": 25
  },
  {
    "Name": "Edgar",
    "LastName": "Villareal",
    "Age": 35
  },
  {
    "Name": "Salvador",
    "LastName": "Ramirez",
    "Age": 20
  }
]
```

Comment: that's right , that wil work for numbers , thank you ! :)