# How to implement OpenWeatherMap 2.0?

Tags: javascript, php, openweathermap

Please can you give me an example about how to implement OpenWheatherMap in a php or Javascript file? I read the Documentation but i don't understand how to do it. Thanks :)

This is my code:

```
<div id="map"> 
        </div>

         <script type="text/javascript">
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
      zoom: 4
    })
  });

  var temp = new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        url: 'http://maps.openweathermap.org/maps/2.0/weather/TA2/{z}/{x}/{y}?date=1527811200&opacity=0.9&fill_bound=true&appid=myAppId',
      })
  });
  map.addLayer(temp);
```

The problem is that the website creates the map, but it doesn't add he temperature layer from OPENWEATHERMAP

Comment: At what point did you get stuck? Have you tried the [sample call](https://openweathermap.org/appid#get): `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID={YOUR API KEY}` The [API documentation](https://openweathermap.org/api) is very straight forward.

Comment: @RobG No because i don't know WHERE to insert it in my code

Comment: Start with [*MDN XMLHttpRequest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), then look for posts like [*How to make an XMLHttpRequest that inserts JSON data into HTML?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44493078/how-to-make-an-xmlhttprequest-that-inserts-json-data-into-html) When you have some code, if you're still having trouble post what you've tried and where it's going wrong.

Comment: @RobG i posted my code, but it doesn't add the temperature layer on the map

Comment: You shouldn't publish your appid, consider removing it from the post (replace it with "myAppId" or similar). Entering the url in a browser returns "Invalid API key".

Comment: @RobG I changed it. So the problem is my Api key? But i'm sure that it's valid